# I am trying to register a staff in my database throuout the form But I get error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models staff and UserAddress and I'm trying to add the staff through models. But I get this error:
AttributeError at /accounts/signup/staff/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
What should I do now, Could some one help me?
I wanted to register a staff but this thing happened.

models.py:

```
class UserAddress(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Staff(CustomUser):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.is_staff = True
            self.is_superuser = False
            return super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

forms.py:

```
class StaffCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        user.email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        address = UserAddress.objects.create(city=self.cleaned_data.get("city"),
                                             address=self.cleaned_data.get("address"),
                                             zip_code=self.cleaned_data.get("zip_code"))

        user.user_address.add(address)

        return user
```

views.py:

```
class StaffSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = StaffCreationForm
    template_name = "accounts/signup_user.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["user_type"] = "staff"
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect("home")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user.user_address` object does not contain any value that is why you're getting this error 
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'` because default it's value is **None** and **None** datatype does not contain `add()` method so try this

```
 user.user_address = address
 user.save() # don't forget to save user
```

this will assign address object to `user.user_address`